# Linux - key (h) is not working

Tags: linux

I am experiencing the issue on my quite freshly installed `Ubuntu` with `Mate GUI` with just a mild amount of apps and additions being added (throughout today), however (I am not able to identify what has caused this) the `h` key stopped working in the GUI.

From what I found I could test, here is some observation I have done so far:

- in the whole GUI (Mate) h-key is not working, but capital H is working, or having an active caps and using shift+h to actually write h
- in GUI in the terminal, I can see the cursor blink activity when h-key is being pushed, but no letter is being written,
- in shortcuts window in the Ubuntu, I have not found anything bound to "h" key,
- in another tty (non-GUI) h-key is working.

Is there a way or something like a safe mode in the Ubuntu I can use to omit the non-essential additions to try it or is there a way I can somehow troubleshoot this behavior? Or track when actuation it is when pressed?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Create a new user; log in as that user; see if the problem persists.  If it does, it's some user-level setting.

Comment: The questioner has already demonstrated that, DopeGhoti, by logging in on a kernel virtual terminal and seeing that the key _works_ there.

Comment: Thank you, yes, Dope, other user was fine. After a reinstall (it was a new system anyway) and consecutive installation of applications it turned out to be Yakuake terminal roll-down utility.